# Can I broadcast different models for each of the clients in federated_tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow-federated

I want to know if we can broadcast different models for each of the clients from the server in tensorflow_federated?

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

Within the TFF language, there is not currently a way to express this. The contract of [`tff.federated_broadcast`](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/federated_broadcast) is that the value that arrives at each client is the *same*. There isn't an alternative communication intrinsic (yet) for other ways of moving tensors from server→clients.

That said, its possible to *simulate* clients that receive different weights. Setup the clients state *outside* TFF in the Python execution environment, then pass in a list (one element for each client). Example:

```py
@tff.tf_computation(MODEL_WEIGHT_TYPE):
def client_work(model_weights):
  # Do local training, or any other logic.


@tff.federated_computation(tff.FederatedType(MODEL_WEIGHT_TYPE, tff.CLIENTS))
def run_one_round(model):
   return tff.federated_map(client_work, model)


client_models = [...]  # a list of each client, possibly different models.
run_one_round(client_models)
```